# I can't select selected checkboxes, what am i doing wrong?

Tags: php

I want to select multiple checkboxes and show the values from those checkboxes.

I'm using MVC, and the function db_query is another function, ignore please

model:

```
function editjo(){
    if(isset($_POST['edit']) && !empty($_POST['editcheck'])) {
    { 

    $editcheckbox = $_POST['editcheck'];
    $countCheckedit = count($_POST['editcheck']);


       $update_jo = "SELECT * FROM offers WHERE table IN ("; 
        foreach($editcheckbox as $key => $value){

       if (($countCheckedit -1) != $key)
       {
       $update_jo .= $editcheckbox[$key].", "; 
       }
       else
       {
       $update_jo .= $editcheckbox[$key].")";
       $update_array = db_query($update_jo, '+');
       }
}
}


editjoview($update_array);

}
}
```

View

```
function editjoview($update_array){

foreach($update_array as $lol){
echo $lol['name'];
}
```

HTML

```
<td><input style='width: 50px;' class='edit' value='Edit' type='submit' name='edit[]' /></td>

  <td><input style='width: 50px;' type='checkbox' name='editcheck[]' value=".$key['id']." /></td>
```

I get the value from all the checkboxes, and i just want to get the value from the checked values

Comment: Umm..so where are you getting the checkbox values?

Comment: i'm getting the checkbox values on view, i created the function on model, and i'm calling the function on view

Comment: I don't see any POST value with `delete` being called. What's the checkbox name you have a problem with?

Comment: You look like you're submitting edit[] and delete[] arrays then looking for editcheck[] which doesn't exist?

Comment: ignore the delete, i posted delete[], it was my fault

Comment: yes, now i changed the delete to editcheck, sorry

Comment: Only the checked items should be submitted, var_dump($_POST) to verify.